# How do I prevent a Google Map from moving when its container is re-sized?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I re-size the container that a Google Map sits inside, is there any way to keep the map in the exact same position regardless of the change?

When I move the left edge of the map container, the map moves right or left, but when I move the right edge of the map container, the map doesn't move at all. Is there any way to reverse this so that if I moved the left edge, the map wouldn't move at all?

This is very similar to what Google is doing with their Results panel on the left side (maps.google.com). The problem is, when I use CSS/JS to re-size everything and re-center (using the setCenter method and calculating what the new center should be), the map flickers occasionally - not all the time, but about 15-20% of the time. I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to work without flickering. I was wondering if there's any method of anchoring the map on the right-hand side?

Open to other ideas as well if anyone can give provide any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to position map in container absolutely with right property specified?

```
<div id="container" style="position:relative">
  <div id="map" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0"></div>
</div>
```

Although result depends on overall layout, it may work.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it was actually something I tried right after posting this question and it did help to a certain extent. There's still some flickering going on though, especially in Firefox (but less than before in Chrome/Safari), so it doesn't fix it entirely, still looking for THE solution. Thanks again!

Comment: is there test page available?